# Is there any way to add overflow hidden to just ONE side?

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I have a slider where the left side of the design is in the grid, but the right side flows out. Is there any way to add overflow hidden to just one side? Like overflow-x-left: hidden; ?

Someone mentioned using clip, but the caveat here is that it actually needs to start from the left side in the grid, lined up with the content above it.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate the insight.

THANK YOU in advance.

**You can see the slider active here (3/4 of the way down), which may help with the WP Bakery container element targeting that should be the container this fits into:** 
https://stable.stable-demos.com/cora/

Layout example:

[image]slider that is supposed to *start* with the left side in the grid, but the right side all the way out to the browser edge.

Here's the current code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // SWIPER FOR CAROUSEL
  var mySwiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container-2', {
    // Optional parameters
    init: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    preloadImages: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto'
  })
});
```

```css
.swiper-container-2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  max-height: 340px;
}

.swiper-container-2:hover {
  cursor: url(https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/curse-custom-v2.png), auto;
}

.swiper-slide div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'gt_sectra_fineregular_italic';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container-2">

  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-1.jpg" />
      <div>This is about this image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-2.jpg" />
      <div>Some information about this one too</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-1.jpg" />
      <div>Wow this is amazing stuff</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .qodef-row-grid-section{
overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: overflow would only overflow on one side anyway - either the right side along the x or the bottom along the y - if you want to show the div from the bottom right or from the right instead of left, maybe absolutely causing the overflow (as the parent would have to have fixed dimensions for overflow hidden anyway)

Comment: I guess one of the solutions from https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ should be adaptable to work on one side only instead of both.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, finally add the code below to solve the problem

```
.vc_row { 
    position: relative;
} // bakery builder row class

.swiper-container-2 { 
    clip-path: inset(-100vw -100vw -100vw -17px); 
}
```